# PowerBI report failed to load in iframe due to denied “X-Frame-Options“ directive set to “SAMEORIGIN“

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Currently working on MVC 5 to load Power BI report in Iframe but getting error like below shot. I tried multiple solutions by adding **?rs:embed=true** and much more but did not get any success. Please help

[image]

Actually report server url hosted on live location and I am accessing it from my localhost.

javascript code:

```
 $('.viewContainer>iframe').attr('src', src);
```

Answer (score -1):

This issue has been fixed after updating the custom header of reporting server.

```
<CustomHeaders>
<Header>
 <Name>X-Frame-Options</Name>
 <Pattern>(?!(http|https):\/\/([^\/]+)\/*xxxxx.*$)</Pattern>
<Value>ALLOW-FROM</Value>
</Header>
   </CustomHeaders>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a link or paste the header which is required to fix this error?